# Starting self hosted WCF services on demand

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, self-hosting

**Is it possible to start self hosted WCF services on demand?**

I see two options to accomplish this:

- Insert a listener in the self hosted WCF's web server and spin up a service host when a request for a specific service comes in, before WCF starts looking for the existence of that endpoint; or
- Integrate a web service in process, start a service host for a request if it isn't running yet and redirect the request to that service host (like I suspect IIS does).

I cannot use IIS or WAS because the web services need to run in process with the UI business logic.

**Which is feasible and how can I accomplish this?**

**EDIT:**
I cannot just start the service hosts because there are hundreds, most (about 95%) of which are (almost) never used but need to be available. This is for exposing a business logic layer of 900 entities.

Comment: Why can't you just spin up the service hosts and be done?

Comment: There are hundreds, most (about 95%) of which are (almost) never used but need to be available. This is for exposing a business logic layer of 900 entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went the following route:

- Create a single service host;
- Create a dynamic proxy which implements all service interfaces;
- Add a service endpoint for every interface the dynamic proxy implements;
- Dispatch to the correct implementation from the dynamic proxy.

Comment: That sounds pretty slick - any chance you could post an example of this approach somewhere?

Comment: It's not that hard :), however it's a good idea to post it somewhere. I do not have a blog. Do you have a suggestion where I could post this?

Comment: You could always put it on CodeProject.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a locator service setup.  Basically always expose a lightweight service that returns the address of the 'actual' services.  Every time the address of a particular service is requested, go ahead and spin it up.

If you're worried about cleaning it up, you could keep a list of the service hosts and wire in some sort of inactivity timeout so you could periodically shut down the service hosts.

There are some design concerns here - the concept of "calling one service before you call another one" is probably considered a bad idea on some level (sounds like coupling the state of two services).

Comment: This would go a long way although it wouldn't be possible for the client to cache the result. The only way this would be reliable if all clients would execute that request before any request they made. I think the overhead of this would be too high.